# How to update complex entities in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

let's say I have the following aggregate:

```py
class Road:
    company_id: int # another aggregate
    name: str
    stops: List[Stop]

    def add_stop(stop: Stop):
        stops.append(stop)

class Stop:
    precission: Precission
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
    address: str
```

This is just a minified example. Let's also say that to create stops, I need to call a third party to geocode the object. Something like:

```py
# this returns a correctly initialized Stop object
StopsDataAccess.get_by_address(address)
```

Now let's say that I want to add a stop to a road, so I would have an application service that would be similar to something like this:

```py
class AddStopToRoadService:
    def run(road_id, address):
        road = RoadRepository.getById(road_id)
        stop = StopsDataAccess.get_by_address(address)
        road.add_stop(stop)
        RoadRepository.save(road)
```

As it is, I do not see a lot of problems with this approach. The problem I have is when the following domain requirement comes:

- Only stops with the precision `EXACT` can be added to a route, those that are `APPROXIMATE` or `UNKNOWN` cannot be added. Also, this can be changed by every company, so for instance, a different company can accept only `APPROXIMATE` or all of them.

So, to approach this I do the following:

```py
class Road:
    ...
    allowed_precission_types: List[Precissions]
    ...

    def add_stop(stop: Stop):
        if stop.precission not in self.allowed_precission_types:
            raise StopNotAllowed()
        stops.append(stop)
```

The `allowed_precission_types` would be filled by the `RoadRepository`. The problem I see with this approach is that that the list of allowed precision values is part of the `Company` aggregate. So I'm not sure if it really fits in there. Am I breaking encapsulation? What would be the correct approach?

Comment: *"that value is part of the Company"* - you mean "the list of allowed precision values", I guess?

Comment: Correct! Fixed!

Comment: Is the allowed precision list on the Company aggregate mutable? If so,  should a change to that collection impact already created roads?

Comment: It’s mutable. That could be changed on the company aggregate and the roads restored using the repository should come with that value updated.

Comment: That complicates it a lot. So if an allowed precision is removed, does that impact already created Stops of that precision?

Comment: No, like, that attribute is not stored with the Roads. It’s added to the Road entity through the Road repository. So the Road repository also loads the allowed precisions from the company aggregate aggregate and “”injects”” them to the Road entity. That’s way I dont like the solution but I have not been able to come up with a different one.

Comment: Well tbh if the current solution fulfills the business rules, I’d keep it as is for now. Alternatives such as storing the allowed precisions in the road aggregate add complexity (eventual consistency) without a clear gain. If requirements change, or talks with domain experts lead to new insights, the model can be changed with the new knowledge.